# Can't display column from different table

Tags: mysql

I am trying to display the driver's first and last name but when I run this query the name columns just return test and not the actual names from the employee table

```
SELECT checklistitem.*,
  m1.Company_ID AS Company_ID,
  m1.ChecklistID As ChecklistID,
  e.FirstName As FirstName,
  e.LastName As LastName
FROM checklistitem
  LEFT JOIN employee e ON e.CompanyID 
  LEFT JOIN maintenance m1 ON m1.CheckListID 
  LEFT JOIN Vehicle v ON m1.LinkedID = v.ID
  LEFT JOIN Trailer t ON m1.LinkedID = t.ID  
WHERE m1.Company_ID = 129
```

I thought maybe the table wasn't linking correctly to find the names so I tried changing the code to `LEFT JOIN employee e ON m1.Company_ID` because both the maintenance and the employee table have a company ID but I get the error

> Unknown column 'm1.Company_ID' in 'on clause'

Comment: there should be a join condition i.e. `on a.a1 = b.b1` not just `on a.a1`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is with the `LEFT JOIN` statements. You have an invalid syntax in your `ON` clause.

```
FROM checklistitem
LEFT JOIN employee e ON e.CompanyID /*ERROR*/
LEFT JOIN maintenance m1 ON m1.CheckListID /*ERROR*/
```

Your SQL statement has to be `table.column = table2.column`

So I'm gonna go out on a guess and say you should being using

```
FROM checklistitem
LEFT JOIN employee e ON checklistitem.CompanyID = e.CompanyID 
LEFT JOIN maintenance m1 ON e.CheckListID = m1.CheckListID
```

Please note: I don't know what your tables are setup like. `checklistitem.CompanyID` and `e.CheckListID` was a guess. Please replace those with the correct fields from your tables.

Also with your table names, `m1.Company_ID` will automatically turn into `Company_ID`. No need to use `AS`.